# Hive Metastore Sql server :thrift.transport.TTransportException: No keytab specified

Tags: hadoop, hive, kerberos, apache-hive

I am trying to run `Hive metastore`.

But it is throwing **error** below.

> org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: No keytab specified**
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S$Server.(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:337)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.createServer(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:104)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.createServer(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:74)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5771)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5701)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212) Exception in thread "main"
>   org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: No keytab specified
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S$Server.(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:337)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.createServer(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:104)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.thrift.HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.createServer(HadoopThriftAuthBridge20S.java:74)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:5771)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:5701)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:212)

Comment: As per this error log it seems that security is enabled in your hadoop cluster.if yes please provide keytab files in hive configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled security, update the following properties in hive-site.xml with keytab file and principal for kerberos.

`hive.metastore.kerberos.keytab.file`

`hive.metastore.kerberos.principal`

or you must disable the security for metastore by setting **false** to the property `hive.metastore.sasl.enabled`